# Launch my app by hotkeys and pass it arguments from Finder (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos

I'm only starting macOS programming. Did some tutorials, reading docs at developers.apple.com. Trying to implement a simple(?) thing, but can't seem to get the whole picture for now.
I want to be able to launch my app by pressing some hot keys combination. The app itself is just a window with a text field that has a list of selected files in Finder (if any). 
Naturally, I'm not asking for a concrete implementation. But some hints and directions on the general structure, or on what concepts and classes to inspect would be very helpful.
macOS 10.13.4, Xcode 9.3.1, Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is to implement a "service". See the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).

A service is a tool that appears in the Services submenu of the application menu and in contextual menus. It can be configured to be invoked by a hot key. The active application at the time the service is invoked cooperates by providing the current selection.